# How to apply toggle class in dynamic way to n number of items?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cmt1").click(function(){
    $("#cmt1").toggleClass("on");
  });
  $(".cmt2").click(function(){
    $("#cmt2").toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

```css
.on { color:red;}
td {border:solid 1px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
<table>
<tr><td class="cmt1"> item 1 <span >X</span></td></tr>
<tr id="cmt1" class=""><td>item 1 sub</td></tr>

<tr><td class="cmt2"> item 1 <span >X</span></td></tr>
<tr id="cmt2" class=""><td>item 1 sub</td></tr>


</table>
</div>
```

How to apply toggle class to n number of items with out hard coded ids for each individual items. need something like n number of ids?
need to add one class for corresponding items of id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cmt1").click(function() {
    $("#cmt1").toggleClass("on");
  });
  $(".cmt2").click(function() {
    $("#cmt2").toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gncveuz5/1/

Comment: Something like this  http://jsfiddle.net/p9z258gs/ ?

Comment: yes. Thanks a lot

Comment: but it works only single class is there . as I have multiple class it's not working :(
http://jsfiddle.net/ng157wh2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure it works with multiple classes, then try the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td[class*=cmt]").click(function() {
    var c = $(this).prop('class').match(/[\w-]*cmt[\w-]*/g)
    $("#" + c).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

**demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td[class*=cmt]").click(function() {
    var c = $(this).prop('class').match(/[\w-]*cmt[\w-]*/g)
    $("#" + c).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

```css
.on {
  color: red;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="row cmt1"> item 1 <span>X</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="cmt1" class="">
      <td>item 1 sub</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="row cmt2"> item 1 <span>X</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="cmt2" class="">
      <td>item 1 sub</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row cmt3"> item 1 <span>X</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="cmt3" class="">
      <td>item 1 sub</td>
    </tr>


  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let cmt=document.querySelector("#cmt1");

cmt.onlick=function(e)
{

  e.target.classList.toggleClass('on');

}
```

If you want multiple Dom's look at .

```
document.queryselectorAll(Dom);
```